# How to replace HTML tags and attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I have a section of code like this

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:-866px;left:1550px;white-space:nowrap" class="xd">some text
```

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:-866px;left:1550px;white-space:nowrap" class="xd">some other text
```

and I need to replace it with

```
<h3>some text</h3>
<h3>some other text </h3>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add javascript tag to this question?  would you rather have a jquery solution? Do you have multiple occurrences?  Are you wanting a totally separate solution for a reason not mentioned?

Comment: javascript, jquery doesn't matter. and yes I have multiple occurrences. sorry to not mentioned before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Javascript to dynamically replace HTML tags with more complicated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336283/use-javascript-to-dynamically-replace-html-tags-with-more-complicated-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery solution:  [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mickmackusa/zcrwz9hy/1/)

```
$('p[class="xd"]').each(function(index,item){
    $(item).replaceWith("<h3>"+$(item).html()+"</h3>");  // keep the text, swap the tags
});
```

---

Thanks to [Vishal Taj PM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422357/vishal-taj-pm) for showing a shorter solution:  [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mickmackusa/zcrwz9hy/2/)

(for this case, there is no difference between `text()` and `html()`)

```
$('p.xd').each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith("<h3>"+$(this).text()+"</h3>")  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a javascript solution

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("xd")[0].outerHTML="<h3>some text</h3>"
</script>
```

```html
<p style="position:absolute;top:-866px;left:1550px;white-space:nowrap" class="xd">some text</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:-866px;left:1550px;white-space:nowrap" class="xd">some text</p>
<script>
  var all_p = document.getElementsByClassName("xd");
  while (all_p.length != 0) {
    all_p[0].outerHTML = "<h3>some text</h3>";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @mickmackusa my apologies, I had to go to work, answer edited due to updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution with Jquery you can use replaceWith(). it will replace existing tag with new one.

**please find the code snippet below.**

```js
$('p.xd').each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith("<h3>"+$(this).text()+"</h3>")  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p style="position:absolute;top:-866px;left:1550px;white-space:nowrap" class="xd">some text</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:-866px;left:1550px;white-space:nowrap" class="xd">some other text</p>
```

Comment: okey i apologize. but you can see both added at the same time. there wasn't any accepted answer while i attempting this answer and too functionality base is different here i used `$(this)` for getting value. and for your information it's not 1 hour late both having just difference of minutes.

Comment: okey then can you remove the down vote. if it is not valid i'm okey to remove post.

Comment: even though it's just a matter of minutes i just tried to help. i would appreciate if you consider my thought.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139264/discussion-between-vishal-taj-pm-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: @sonubreeze This answer is more refined than mine and keeps the demo on SO.  Please move the accepted answer to this one.  I'd like to delete mine so that Vishal gets the green tick (but I can't while it has the green tick).  This is the code that future SO readers should be using.